# Why are most badges received delayed?

Tags: support, review, badges

There are many badges that are received after, especially the less common ones, like the ones except `Teacher`, `Student`, `Scholar` etc.

Do they require moderators approval? But, that would not scale, would it? There are hundreds and hundreds of badges and would be too much work for moderators to approve all of those. Or is there some kind of peer approval process?

I'd have expected that badges could be awarded immediately when an achievement happens?

- What process awards badges to users, why does it take so long?
- Is there a manual approval process for badges?

Comment: Care to explain the reason of downvote!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most badges are awarded by batch processes.

These processes run periodically, the delay is between you reaching the criteria and the batch process that awards the specific badge running.

There is no manual approval, badges are always awarded automatically.